# Win 8.1 connected to PPTP VPN, DNS not working

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn, pptp

I have a server `A` (Windows Server 2008 R2) and a client `B` (Windows 8.1) in different locations.

I set up a VPN server on `A`. Since I have only one NIC on `A`, I chose custom configuration and enabled VPN and NAT. I added a static address range (10.0.0.200 ~ 10.0.0.220) in IPv4 pool, and created a new interface under RRAS\IPv4\NAT.

Now if I connect from `B` to `A`, DNS is not working. For example, I can browse `http://173.194.127.212/`, but not `http://www.google.com/`. I'm sure VPN is working because if I don't connect to `A` first, I'm not even able to browse google with IP address, don't ask me why.

What I have tried so far:

1. Allowing port 53 for TCP and UDP both inbound and outbound, and even shutdown the firewall on `A`;
2. Manually setting the IPv4 dns server address for the VPN connection on `B`;
3. Run `netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsservers name="xxx" address=all validate=no` after connecting on `B`;

Here is some diagnostic infomation on `B`:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nslookup www.google.com
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
服务器:  UnKnown
Address:  8.8.8.8

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** 请求 UnKnown 超时

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

正在 Ping 8.8.8.8 具有 32 字节的数据:
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=72ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=51ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=59ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=70ms TTL=49

8.8.8.8 的 Ping 统计信息:
    数据包: 已发送 = 4，已接收 = 4，丢失 = 0 (0% 丢失)，
往返行程的估计时间(以毫秒为单位):
    最短 = 51ms，最长 = 72ms，平均 = 63ms

C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers

接口 "xxx" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            8.8.8.8
                                          61.139.2.69
    用哪个前缀注册:                   无

接口 "vEthernet (Internal Ethernet Port Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch)" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            无
    用哪个前缀注册:                   只是主要

接口 "vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE 系列控制器 Virtual Switch)" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            61.139.2.69
                                          8.8.4.4
    用哪个前缀注册:                   只是主要

接口 "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            无
    用哪个前缀注册:                   无
```

Here is infomation on `A`:

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup www.google.com
服务器:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

非权威应答:
名称:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2404:6800:4005:806::1010
          173.194.127.208
          173.194.127.211
          173.194.127.212
          173.194.127.209
          173.194.127.210


C:\Windows\system32>ping 8.8.8.8

正在 Ping 8.8.8.8 具有 32 字节的数据:
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=32ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=33ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=31ms TTL=49
来自 8.8.8.8 的回复: 字节=32 时间=72ms TTL=49

8.8.8.8 的 Ping 统计信息:
    数据包: 已发送 = 4，已接收 = 4，丢失 = 0 (0% 丢失)，
往返行程的估计时间(以毫秒为单位):
    最短 = 31ms，最长 = 72ms，平均 = 42ms

C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers

接口 "RAS (Dial In) Interface" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            无
    用哪个前缀注册:                   无

接口 "本地连接 9" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            8.8.8.8
                                          61.139.2.69
    用哪个前缀注册:                   只是主要

接口 "Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1" 的配置
    静态配置的 DNS 服务器:            无
    用哪个前缀注册:                   只是主要
```

Comment: Are you expecting all DNS resolution to be done via the remote network you've VPN'd into, or locally?  If locally: Have you tried enabling split tunneling on the client yet? If remote: Does the VPN server have routing setup to route the DNS requests?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'd like to use remote DNS. This is the first time I setup a VPN server, where do I setup routing DNS requests?